# Category slug inside another php code

Tags: php

I'm using this code to get category slug on categories archive page outside of the loop:

```
<?php $cat = get_term_by('name', single_cat_title('',false), 'category'); echo $cat->slug; ?>
```

And I would like to know how can I add the result of that code inside 'base' => '/HERE/' of paginate_links php code that looks like this:

```
<?php echo paginate_links( array( 'current' => $current_paginate_page, 'show_all' => true,'prev_next' => false, 'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages, 'base' => '/HERE/', 'format' => '%#%' )); ?>
```

I just don't know how to correctly write it inside another php code. Please help, thank you!

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/single_cat_slug?replies=5
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: `"/$cat/"` ?.. Please note the purely programming questions are [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and are better asked at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any kind of (single or double) quotations:

... `'base' => $cat,` ...

about quotations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php